# How to properly skip a step if 2 conditions are true

Tags: c#, operators, logic, conditional-statements

I have two conditions, `ShouldCheckForErrors` and `HasErrors`

My code is

```
if(ShouldCheckForErrors && HasErrors)
{
    //Do nothing
}
else
{
    PassTest()
}
```

I feel like this is a very longwinded check.  Isn't there a way that I can do a single check without having to use `else`?

For example:

```
if(!ShouldCheckForErrors && !HasErrors)
{
    PassTest()
}
```

does not work, because that would fail to call `PassTest()` when `ShouldCheckforErrors` is `true`, but `HasErrors` is `false`. (And vice versa)

I just feel like I am forgetting something with my Logical Operators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

```
if (!ShouldCheckForErrors || !HasErrors)
```

To put it differently:

> You should pass either if there are no errors, or if we aren't checking errors.

Comment: acording to the first code (which is "longer"), pass means that *both* of them are true, this is not *or*, but *and*.

Comment: @Tigran: That's not how negation works.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: That's the good way. Now I'm not sure how @Adil answer compiles to, but I'd think that both condition are checked where as here, `HasErrors` will not be checked if `!ShouldCheckForErrors` evaluate to `true`

Comment: Given the novice of the user, you probably want to explain DeMorgan's laws or their relevance or use here, rather than leaving a fairly dense Wikipedia article to a beginner.

Comment: @Tigran: `!(A && B) === (!A || !B)`

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I was looking for.  I really like that this takes advantage of the Short Circuiting nature of C# to improve performance as well.

Answer (score 5):

Use not operator `!` after you get result of both conditions

```
if(!(ShouldCheckForErrors && HasErrors))
{
    PassTest();
}
```

Comment: Didn't see this before I posted +1

Comment: Very clean, but I decided to go with `(!ShouldCheckForErrors || !HasErrors)`  to prevent calling the second condition unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is a bit off

```
!ShouldCheckForErrors && !HasErrors
```

is not the same as

```
!(ShouldCheckForErrors && HasErrors)
```

which is what I believe you want

Answer (score 1):

Simpler case -

```
if(theOnlyCheck) {

}
else {
    do();
}
```

You seem to be savvy enough to shorten *this* check -

```
if(!theOnlyCheck) {
    do();
}
```

But you simply mess up your order of operations.

Substitute `(check1 && check2)` for `theOnlyCheck`. Don't forget parentheses:

```
if(!(check1 && check2)) {
    do();
}
```

Now if you don't like dealing with these parentheses you can follow De Morgan's Law:  `!(a && b)` is the same as `!a || !b`.  Think it through yourself to see -

```
if(!check1 || !check2) {
    do();
}
```